# Incompatibilidad de versión mysqldump en MySQL Workbench v8.0.12

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Necesito hacer respaldo de una base de datos remotamente, esto ya lo hacía con anterioridad, me mostraba el error de compatibilidad de la versión de SQL Workbench y del SQL del servidor.

Pero volví a instalar MySQL Workbench y ahora no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al intentar exportar aparece este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al intentar exportar me aparecen puros errores que terminan en:

```
 Unknown table 'column_statistics' in information_schema (1109)
 Operation failed with exitcode 2
```

Ya intenté una solución a esto que es ir a

> Edit -> Preferences… -> Administration

Y de ahí, en el campo "Path to mysqldump Tool" puse buscar un directorio para un archivo de "mysqldump.exe"

Intenté con los siguientes:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe
```

Y con

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe
```

Pero ninguno funciona.

Solamente quiero exportar las tablas de la base de datos, pero no sé por qué no funciona si antes lo hacía.

Comment: Es que esa opción viene activada por defecto. Agrega esta bandera al comando:`--column-statistics=0` para desactivarla.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema la version de mi workbench de de 8.0.21 y la version de dump de mi servidor es de 10.1.45 la bronca es que work bench un no saca esa version del .exe, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución no era muy complicado, simplemente no me esperaba que algo así funcionara.

Básicamente, por lo que he visto, los programas que manejan SQL (Sea MySQL Server o MySQL Workbench) utilizan un ".exe" para exportar información de una base de datos o una base de datos. Y pues como es de esperar con el paso del tiempo, se van actualizando los programas y con ellos los "mysqldump.exe".

Mi problema en específico era que mi MySQL Workbench maneja una versión más antigua que MySQL Server del servidor que consultaba remotamente. Así que lo que sucedía es que el "mysqldump.exe" de MySQL Workbench (mi ordenador) era anticuado al "mysqldump.exe" de MySQL Server (servidor).

Así que la solución fue buscar en los archivos del MySQL del servidor y buscar el archivo "mysqldump.exe", mandarlo a la mi computadora, y lo reemplacé con el "mysqldump.exe" del directorio

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe

Aunque creo que el directorio es indistinto, el punto es que en la pantalla de "Administration" tenga el "mysqldump.exe" copiado del servidor.

La idea principal es que ambos, tanto la computadora que consulta como el servidor tengan una versión compatible del "mysqldump.exe", y la versión del "mysqldump.exe" ahora para ambos es 10.1.30.

Comment: Ohhh, eso te lo decía claramente debajo de donde dice: **mysqldump Version Mismatch**. Creí que te interesaba mantener diferentes versiones por algún motivo.

Comment: Sí, me di cuenta cuando lo encontré en un foro de hace años, y la verdad lo había pensado, pero por ser diferentes programas de diferentes versiones no creí que funcionaría, y no sabía como hacerlo, fue gracias a un foro antiguo en que encontré esa solución. Y no, no buscaba eso jeje, creo que no me di a entender bien al principio. Pero voy a dejar la pregunta porque vi otras preguntas similares o iguales a la mía que no fueron resueltos.

Comment: Si hay alguien que esté mas adentrado a SQL y pudiera mejorar/corregir mi respuesta lo agradecería.

Comment: La mejor respuesta es la que has dado tú: **igualar las versiones**.  Pero cuando esto no es posible, la salida es desactivar `column-statistics` para que funcione en versiones distintas. [Ver la explicación aquí](https://serverfault.com/q/912162)

Answer (score 2):

Aquí le dejo un video donde se explica como solucionar dicho error, espero les ayude.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf2SeSxmhBs

La solución consiste en descargarse MySQL Community Server correcto y configurarse en el workbench.